# CSS keep menu in container and expand background to full screen

Tags: css

The picture below shows what I would like to get.

It is a menu within a container, where the menu may wrap to multiple lines when the window/screen gets too narrow for all menu items to fit in. At the same time I would like the menu to have a background which expands to full screen in width, while expanding in height with the menu when it gets wrapped to multiple lines. Currently I think this is not possible with CSS, but I am also just a CSS amateur. My current solution involves @media queries to set the height of the menu background for resolutions where wrapping appears. This does not take into account that font-size could change, thus making each line of menu higher.

Here is a jsFiddle with a basic setup, which does NOT what I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/n3jmyq2f/3/ (Edited, was not the final version)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu_wrap">
        <div class="menu_bg"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="content">It's me, Mario!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:lightgreen;
    height:300px;
}
.menu_bg{
    position: absolute;
    background: #afafaf;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    height:30px;
    z-index: -1;
}
ul {
    height:30px;
    background: #afafaf;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[image: css menu with background]

Comment: `.container {width:85%}` change this and see

Comment: @Abdulla thanks, but this was probably based on my first fiddle, which was not the finished, sorry, so this does not apply in my case.

Comment: ya i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the simplest.

Stop thinking of the `.container` as something that must contain **everything**. It's just a class that can be reused as and when required.

If you take the menu div out of the "container" but put a `.container` div **inside** you get the effect you are looking for.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/n3jmyq2f/14/)

```css
*,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.menu {
  background: #afafaf;
}
ul {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">It's me, Mario!</div>
</div>
```

***2nd Option***

Use a pseudo-element

```css
*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 300px;
}
ul {
  background: #afafaf;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">It's me, Mario!</div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/n3jmyq2f/15/)

Comment: thanks, but either you have misunderstood me, or your jsFiddles are not working as I expect. Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3jmyq2f/13/ and make the result view such narrow, that all menu items are in one column. Please have a look at this image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2rghlht.jpg. Both you examples do not expand the menu background to he menu height when window is resized small enough.

Comment: Try removing the height from the `ul` - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/n3jmyq2f/14/ and https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/n3jmyq2f/15/

Comment: wow, thank you very much, the second one looks like the one I need. The first one changes element order, in my case the html structure comes from a CMS and I don't want to change that part. The :before element does the trick in the second one obviously :-), thanks learned. But so it seems that it is not possible to achieve the result with a "real" div while keeping the html structure.

Comment: one more thing, this solution invokes the horizontal scroll bar, and overflow-x:hidden does not help. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not as such, I'd have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

if in `.container` you change

```
     width:50%;
```

to

```
     width:100%;
```

it will do it

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/n3jmyq2f/10/)

---

you could also use the `.menu-wrap` class (which I've seen in your markup) to do this

Comment: Thanks, but the container must not be 100%, as it is intended to keep the main content centered on screen, as well as to keep it visually to the design layout .

Comment: then you can use another **wrapper** , i edited the fiddle check it out

Comment: Pleas have a look at my edited fiddle, the one posted first was not finished. The container is screen centered, the menu should respect the borders of the container.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is wrapping the content of menu in another `.container` div

Comment: thanks, I checked also your latest fiddle, but this involves changing html structure, here I am trying to get a solution with the structure presented.